# Uploading Csv Not Working after Modification

Tags: php, mysql, csv

```
          <?php  
        session_start();

          //Check whether the session variable SESS_MEMBER_ID is present or not
        if(!isset($_SESSION['sess_user_id']) || (trim($_SESSION['sess_user_id']) == '')) {
header("location: index.php");
exit();
      }
 include ("../config.php");
if(isset($_POST["Import"]))
{
 echo $filename=$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
 if($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 0)
 {
  $file = fopen($filename, "r");
  //$sql_data = "SELECT * FROM prod_list_1";
  while (($emapData = fgetcsv($file, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE)
  {
   //print_r($emapData);
   //exit();
    $sql="INSERT INTO client (fid, fname, mname, lname, address, contact_num, category, bank, card_num, pin_num, salary_sched, salary, stat) VALUES
   ('$emapData[0]','$emapData[1]','$emapData[2]','$emapData[3]','$emapData[4]','$emapData[5]','$emapData[6]','$emapData[7]','$emapData[8]','$emapData[9]','$emapData[10]','$emapData[11]','$emapData[12]')";
   $res=$con->query($sql);
   // $res=$con2->query($sql);
  }
   fclose($file);
   echo 'CSV File has been successfully Imported';
 }
 else
  echo 'Invalid File: Please Upload CSV File';
}
  header("Location: ../clerk.php");

?>
```

I only copied these on my other `php` file and it is working. But I do not understand why it is not after modifying adding `$emapData`

Can someone please help me?

Heres the sample of the  first fIle which is working.

```
<?php  
session_start();

//Check whether the session variable SESS_MEMBER_ID is present or not
if(!isset($_SESSION['sess_user_id']) || (trim($_SESSION['sess_user_id']) == '')) {
    header("location: index.php");
    exit();
}

include ("../config.php");
if(isset($_POST["Import"]))
{
 echo $filename=$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
 if($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 0)
 {
  $file = fopen($filename, "r");
 while (($emapData = fgetcsv($file, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE)
  {
   //print_r($emapData);
   //exit();
   $sql = "INSERT INTO grades (stud_id, code, sub_desc, units, year, sem, prof, grade) VALUES 
 ('$emapData[0]', 
'$emapData[1]',
'$emapData[2]',
'$emapData[3]',
'$emapData[4]',
'$emapData[5]',
'$emapData[6]',
'$emapData[7]')";
 $res=$con->query($sql);
  // $res=$con2->query($sql);
     }
     fclose($file);
     echo 'CSV File has been successfully Imported';
     }
     else
      echo 'Invalid File: Please Upload CSV File';
    }
     header("Location: ../success.php");

    ?>
```

Comment: print the $sql. and try it manually and ensure that there is no mysql error

Comment: I know it its, not the Php File file... its the Form... Thanks.. I now know how to go with this kind of Problems....